# variable value is not changing when i am changing the value with a function in js

Tags: javascript

```
    function show() {
        let date_ = new Date();
    
        let sec = String(date_.getSeconds());
        fill_gaps(sec);
    
        function fill_gaps(candidate) {
            if (candidate.length < 2) {
            candidate = "0" + candidate;
          } else {
          candidate = candidate;
         }
       }
    
        time_ = String(`${sec}`);
        console.log(time_)
      }
```

The `fill_gaps()` function is supposed to change the var sec value; but it isn't changing the value outside the function. My guess is that it is not changing on global scope.

I know this is a basic problem but I can't figure it out as I am still a beginer.

Expected:

```
console.log(time_) = 0("and the current second")
```

Actual:

```
console.log(tiem_) = ("the current second")
```

Comment: strings are passed as a value inside the function in JS not as a reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: are you declaring a function inside another function?

Comment: Chris G - am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** You were missing a return statement in your `fill_gaps` function, you were calling it but you weren't doing anything with it

```js
function show() {
  let date_ = new Date();

  let sec = String(date_.getSeconds());
  sec = fill_gaps(sec); //call your function like this, save its value inside the sec variable

  time_ = String(`${sec}`);
  console.log(time_)
}

//this outside, it is a separate function
function fill_gaps(candidate) {
  if (candidate.length < 2) {
    candidate = "0" + candidate;
  } else {
    candidate = candidate;
  }
  return candidate;//you were missing a return statement
}

show();
```

Comment: yeah this works. but i need to use that function multiple times. p.s- i haven't shared the full code..

Comment: thanks for the help man... i was stuck on this simple prob for hours... thanks a lot

Comment: too bad i can't upvote your answer... i am new to stack and need some reputation first

Comment: you can mark the answer as accepted instead :)